Prevent IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1 open XLS files internally
After latest update of IDEA, when I click to .xls file inside my project, it tries to open it in tab. But I want to open it with associated application, not inside IDEA.
As work around I can right click and from context menu I can select "Open in associated app" - but this is what I do not want to do :)
I tried to find settings to return previous behavior, but without luck.
Does anybody know how to change it?
Thx

Now excel files will open by default inside DataGrip/Database plugin.
You can change the behaviour in advanced settings

